# How do i get a button to delete the index its attached to in an array when clicked?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm creating a multiple choice quiz that enables the user to input their own questions and answers and from there develop a quiz. I want to give the users the ability to delete questions stored in the questionBank, and I'm having trouble deleting questions the user has stored.

Here is what i have so far

```
bodyText = bodyText + '<button onClick="questionBank.splice(1,1)">Delete me</button>';
```

How do i get it so that when the user clicks on the button, it deletes the element in the array the button is attached to? I understand that the splice (1,1) is only deleting the first element stored in the array and not the element the button is attached to.

Comment: Please post enough code to make the problem reproducible. From this code I see no array declaration nor do I quite understand what you mean by the element the button is attached to. Technically you have concatenated the html for a button to bodyText and stored it in bodyText.

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear how your question bank works which may well affect the final solution that works best.
But you will need, at the very least, to pass the ID of the question into delete function.
So your html could look this:

```
bodyText = bodyText + '<button onClick="deleteQuestion(12)">Delete me</button>';
```

And then have a function that handles the splice:

```
function deleteQuestion(id) {
    questionBank.splice(id,1);
}
```

You should be able to add the ID to the button click without too much trouble when you create the HTML for the page.